# ¿Como actualizar datos de una relación de muchos a mucho en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

alguien sabe como se actualizan los datos de una relación de muchos a muchos en laravel.

- Quiero actualizar los datos de la tabla pivote que se llama **pedidos_productos** con los campos:
- pedido_id
- producto_id
- cantidad
- estado

Estos son los modelos:

```html
class Pedido extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'pedidos';

   public function productos(){
      return $this->belongsToMany(Producto::class)
   }
}


class Producto extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'productos';

   public function pedidos(){
      return $this->belongsToMany(Pedido::class)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Buenas puedes usar el metodo updateExistingPivot.

```
$producto = Producto::findOrFail($productoId);
$producto->pedidos()->updateExistingPivot($pedidoId, ['cantidad' => $cantidad , 'estado' => 'Pagado']);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @pwron esta perfecta tu solución.